# postMessageId error with reCaptcha on localhost

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

Currently I'm making single page application with jQuery only and I'm using reCaptcha 2.0 just as example to cover screen design. Apparently when I put recaptcha script in head (or after footer), and call g-recaptcha div with sitekey (personal, or test key from their official website) it gives an error in console:
"Cannot read property 'postMessageId' of null"..

It comes from iframes.js

I do not use any php with this, just plain html, css and jquery.

Please do not down vote because I didn't provide any code. If needed I will provide it, but I think that question is more/less straight forward.

Thanks

Comment: Well your code is sort of important .. Because ReCaptcha has had issues with being able to "find" the textarea or div to fill in the token.   Especially if tables are used.  It's these "known issues" that can be resolved quickly if one can peek at the simple form / JS you are using.

Comment: Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/vuliniar/pen/rZjBpr

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same issue and also found this post on gitHub: 
https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/100
iamaleko mentions that recaptcha can't get contentWindow in time. I would guess that your app is loading the captcha to early?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort, but I already saw that issue. Anyways, error stills shows up. It shows up on every single page I try to access that has recaptcha on it. Even on their official demo: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Comment: I checked other browsers and only had the issue in chrome. Deactivated all plugins but also has not changed a thing.